# Distributed System: Leader Election

Tags: algorithm, protocols, distributed-system

I'm currently working on a Distributed System where we have to implement some kind of [Leader Election](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leader_election).
The problem is that we would like to avoid that all computers have to know each other - but only the leader. Is there a fast way where we can use for instance Broadcast to achieve what we want?

Or does we simply have to know at least one, to perform a good Leader Election?

It is assumable that all computers is on same subnet.

Comment: With the description of the problem you give, it's hard to do anything else but refer you to the wikipedia article you already gave. Can you give more details, maybe say why the algorithms listed in the wikipedia page didn't provide what you need?

Comment: Hi Blubb. As far as i can see The algorithms on the wikipedia page require that all computers knows all other computers.
But i would like to find a solution which work when they dont know each other. Can you follow me?
What is the cost of using multicast/broadcast. Is it linear to the number of computers in the group, or does it only depend on the amount of data you wanna send?

Comment: Not really. For example, I don't see how the [Bully algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bully_algorithm) would rely on computers knowing each other. In fact, it relies on broadcasting. Could you give a precise description of what 'knowing each other' means in technical or graph-theoretic terms?

Comment: Additionally, you should specify what failure-model you are assuming. Do you assume that all computers are up and running (correctly) all the time? Do you assume that computers may suddenly die? Or even go crazy and act maliciously?

Comment: Hi Blubb.
What i mean by, not knowing each other, is that we have a not connected graph (no edges contained).
We of cause must handle computers who suddenly die.

How should bullet algorithm work, if they dont know each other. We cant compare unique id's if we dont know them?

Answer (score 14):

> The problem is that we would like to avoid that all computers have to know each other - but only the leader.

Leader election is the problem of picking a single leader out of a set of potential leader candidates. Look at it as having two required properties: *liveness* and *safety*. Here, *liveness* would mean "most of the time, there is a leader", while *safety* would mean "there are either zero or one leaders". Let's consider how we would solve this safety property in your example, using broadcast.

Let's pick a simple (broken) algorithm, assuming every node has a unique ID. Each node broadcasts its ID and listens. When receiving a higher ID than its own, it stops participating. If it receives a lower ID than its own, it sends broadcasts its own again. Assuming a synchronous network, the last ID everybody receives is the leader's ID. Now, introduce a network partition. The protocol will happily continue on either side of the partition, and two leaders will be elected.

That's true of this broken protocol, but it's also true of all possible protocols. How do you tell the difference between nodes you can't communicate with and nodes that don't exist if you don't know (at least) how many nodes exist? So there's a first *safety* result: you need to know how many nodes exist, or you can't ensure there is only one leader.

Now, let's relax our *safety* constraint to be a probabilistic one: "there can be zero or more leaders, but most of the time there is one". That makes the problem tractable, and a widely-used solution is gossip (epidemic protocols). For example, see [A Gossip-Style Failure Detection Service](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.20.5411) which discusses a variant of this exact problem. The paper mainly concerns itself with probabilistically correct failure detection and enumeration, but if you can do that you can do probabilistically correct leader election too.

As far as I can tell, you can't have safe non-probabilistic leader election in general networks without at least enumerating the participants.

Comment: Actually, there is a way to avoid knowing all leaders. All it takes is a reliable meeting point. Think of "parking spot". We don't know all possible drivers. Still, there is at most one car parked.

Answer (score 1):

As one of interesting 'distributed mechanics' solutions I have see last time I'd recommend Apache [zookeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org/) project. This is open source solution so at least you should be able to get couple of ideas from there. Also it is intensively developing so probably you can reuse it just as part of your solution.

> ZooKeeper is a centralized service for maintaining configuration
>   information, naming, providing distributed synchronization, and
>   providing group services. All of these kinds of services are used in
>   some form or another by distributed applications. Each time they are
>   implemented there is a lot of work that goes into fixing the bugs and
>   race conditions that are inevitable. Because of the difficulty of
>   implementing these kinds of services, applications initially usually
>   skimp on them ,which make them brittle in the presence of change and
>   difficult to manage. Even when done correctly, different
>   implementations of these services lead to management complexity when
>   the applications are deployed.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend JGroups to solve this problem - assuming you are building a system on top of the JVM.

http://www.jgroups.org/

Use the LockService to ensure that only 1 node in the cluster is the leader. JGroups can be set up to use a Peer Lock or a Central Lock - either should work in your case.

See http://withmeta.blogspot.com/2014/01/leader-election-problem-in-elastic.html for a Clojure implementation, or http://javabender.blogspot.com.au/2012/01/jgroups-lockservice-example.html for a Java one.

Comment: The question does not imply Java or any language in particular.

Answer (score 1):

A practical solution is to use DB as "meeting" point.

This solution is VERY handy specially if you are already using SQL DB, all it takes is a new table. If you're using DB cluster, you can take advantage of its high availability.

Here is the table my implementation uses:

```
CREATE TABLE Lease (
  ResourceId varchar(64),
  Expiration datetime,
  OwnerId varchar(64),
  PRIMARY KEY(ResourceId)
);
```

The idea is to have a row per shared resource. Leaders will compete for the same row.

My over simplified C# implementation looks likes this:

```
class SqlLease {
  private ISqlLeaseDal _dal;
  private string _resourceId;
  private string _myId;

  public SqlLease(ISqlLeaseDal dal, string resourceId) {
    _dal = dal;
    _resourceId = resourceId;
    _myId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
  }

  class LeaseRow {
      public string ResourceId {get; set;}
      public string OwnerId {get; set;}
      public Datetime Expiration {get; set;}
      public byte[] RowVersion {get; set;}
  }

  public bool TryAcquire(Datetime expiration) {
    expiration = expiration.ToUniversalTime();
    if (expiration < DateTime.UtcNow) return false;
    try {
      var row = _dal.FindRow(_resourceId);
      if (row != null) {
        if (row.Expiration >= DateTime.UtcNow && row.OwnerId != _myId) {
          return false;
        }
        row.OwnerId = _myId;
        row.Expiration = expiration;
        _dal.Update(row);
        return true;
      }
      _dal.Insert(new LeaseRow {
        ResourceId = _resourceId,
        OwnerId = _myId,
        Expiration = expiration,
      });
      return true;
    } catch (SqlException e) {
      if (e.Number == 2601 || e.Number == 2627) return false;
      throw e;
    } catch (DBConcurrencyException) {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

The `ISqlLeaseDal` class encapsulates SQL connection and low level access to table.

Use reasonable deadlines. Remember that in case current leader fails, resource will be locked until expiration ends.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it doesn't scale. If you keep on using the DB for every leader election situation you stumble upon in a bigger platform, soon enough the DB is strangled by handling locks and cannot serve data. I've seen this happen in real life unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

@Marc has described it very well. I would like to add some points over it.

If all the participating systems must not know about each other then the broadcasting ID (or say timestamp) does not reveal its state unless it is elected as a leader.
Once being elected as a leader, it can now broadcast the state of the machine for all other nodes in the cluster to connect to.

If the participating systems must not reveal their presence at all then there must be a system to communicate for e.g. a DB (as mentioned by Igor), a TCP based system or a mounted location (the way zookeeper elects)
where all the machines state is stored but the least (or the first one is available with read permission) and leader keeps on updating its state to this system.
If the leader goes down then the system chooses the next node as the leader by making it available to read to other nodes cleans up the last leader entry.

Zookeeper creates an ephemeral node available to read to all the nodes. This behavior can be overridden by making only the top node available to read whenever there is a change in the cluster state.

Concurrency can be an issue only if a large number of nodes start at the same time (in milliseconds) and the intermediate system takes too long to return a minuscule result.